# which one is better to implement restful web services among JAX-RS and SPRING RESTFUL API?

Tags: rest

I have gone through the jax-rs implementation of restful webservices and spring rest template also. I am feeling like both works fine. Help me to decide which one works better with large amount of data....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Rest support is based on MVC and its not actual implementation of JAX-RS.If your application is already on spring and you don't have any constraint to use Jersey,Spring Rest will make sense.

JAX-RS is just specification and you can replace jersey with apache cxf or RestEasy.

refer : [Spring MVC and JAX-RS compliant frameworks](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IpYv5t3tYrH3JkctwkNQZmt8c19TAC0hxIrBdorT4y4/edit)

[Spring 4 vs Jersey for REST web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305363/spring-4-vs-jersey-for-rest-webservices)

Comment: My application is not on spring, i am building a new application to handle large amount of data...  So is jersey works better than spring for me..? i have gone through the document u shared it saying both are almost same...!!

Comment: spring MVC is part of the Spring framework 

it already integrates with the Spring IoC container and lot of framework features like AOP,ORM support etc

It also integrates seamlessly with Spring Data, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, 
Spring Security also has  support for various view technologies such as JSP, Velocity ,Freemarker which you can take the advantage. Now you decide based on your needs and design.

Comment: Ok,I will go with Spring.