# Difference between @Path and @Requestmapping in REST webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, path

I am working in REST webservice. I was going through some blogs and there I saw for mapping of URL to a method, they used different annotations.
Some places used `@RequestMapping` and some places used `@Path`. 
How does both differ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on the framework that creates the Web service

`@RequestMapping` is an annotation used in Spring framework
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

`@Path` is an annotation used in frameworks implementing JAX-RS API, such as Jersey
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2001

If you want to know which one is better, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305363/spring-4-vs-jersey-for-rest-web-services) may help