# Difference between @Path and @Webmethod

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

Can some one tell me the where should be `@WebMethod` used and where @Path or `@RequestMapping` should be used?

Recently I came through a code where `@webmethod` is used, till now I have been using @path and `@requestmapping` for implementing my webservices.
Well, the code with Webmethod was using SOAP webservices.

Is it something to do with SOAP or REST? or Java or J2EE?

I have tried googling, but no success till now.

```java
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetPendingrequest")
public abstract ERxPendingRequestsCounts getERxPendingCountsForProvider(@WebParam(name = "pvid") BigDecimal pvid)
  throws SystemFault,SecurityFault, IllegalArgumentFault;
```

Comment: I think this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628374/difference-between-path-and-requestmapping-in-rest-webservice

Comment: `@Path` is a JAX-RS annotation while `@RequestMapping` is used in a Spring application. You do not mention Spring so I assume that using the later annotation will not work for you. `@WebMethod` is SOAP while `@Path` REST; very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Path` is a **JAX-RS** notation. `@WebMethod` is the standard **JAX-WS** notation that tells that this particular method should be exposed as a public operation of the WebService.

Note:
**JAX-RS** is specification that deals with **RESTful** interfaces while **JAX-WS** is the corresponding one for **SOAP**.

You can find more details on standard JAX-WS annotations here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webserv/annotations.html#wp1040606

Comment: Worth noting that `@RequestMapping` is Spring.

Comment: @LutzHorn - agreed. But his question was related to whether webmethod has something to do with SOAP.